# pass String to function writing javascript

Tags: javascript, java, string

I'm trying to pass a string argument to JavaScript function.
for some reason, it can get only ints.
I put here only the syntax of the string, since I know that this is the problem because it worls with int.

Code inside sending function:

```
String counter = "hey";
out.println("<script>parent.update(\'' + counter + '\')</script>");
out.flush();
```

Eventually I'd expect following `update` function on my HTML page to be called with value of `counter` as shown above:

```
 <script>
      function update(p) { alert(p); }
 </script>
```

as I mentioned, the javascript file does alert when I send an int, but doesn't react when I send a string.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Java and javascript, as I mentioned

Comment: Any errors in javascript file?

Comment: Where did you mention java? Anyways.. added tag

Comment: sorry, my bad, its java. and there are no errors, as i said, it can get an int and do everything easily, but cant work with a string

Comment: Does this work?
`out.println("<script>parent.update('" + counter + "')</script>");`

Comment: @engineer thank you very much!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do called "string interpolation" and used in other languages - you can have formatting string and get values automatically inserted to it.

The code you've used does not do that - since you pass just single string to `out.println` it is printed as is.

Your options

- construct string with concatenation

  ```
  out.println("<script>parent.update('" +
     counter + 
     "')</script>");
  ```
- use String.format as shown in [String variable interpolation Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389827/string-variable-interpolation-java)

  ```
  out.println(String.Format("<script>parent.update('%s')</script>",
     counter));
  ```

Note: if value you are trying to pass to JavaScript function may contain quotes (especially if coming from user's input) you'd need to escape it first.