# String Formatting Java

Tags: java, string, formatting, string-formatting

Other languages like Python, JavaScript, and C# have simple string formatting. Does Java have it's own version of this? I did a Google search and couldn't find anything, but I'm hoping it's not the case.

For those who don't understand the question, here's an example of the other languages.

Python:

```
f'Hello {name}!
```

JavaScript:

```
`Hello ${name}!`
```

C#:

```
$"Hello {name}!"
```

Comment: I think you should update your question and mention, to clarify, that `name` is a _variable_. And the term that you're looking for is _interpolation_. You should mention that in your question as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is *interpolation* (the detection and replacement with its value) of *variables* or *expressions* inside *String literals*. Java has no such feature. In Java, you will have to revert to:

- String concatenation, for example `StringBuilder.append()`
- String formatting, for example `PrintStream.printf()`, `PrintWriter.printf()`, `String.format()`

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.format`

The syntax is a bit different from other language since it is position based instead of var based. If you need var based interpolator, the closest thing is `StringBuilder`.

Also see [String variable interpolation Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389827/string-variable-interpolation-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
 String s = "Something";
 System.out.printf("My name is: %s", s);
```

for console output. Or you can use String.format