# Java/kotlin format string that read from file using array

Tags: java, kotlin

As title says, I want to know is there any convent way to format string using array in Java.

Let me hold an kotlin example.

```
var sentences = arrayOf("hello", "world")
var template = "Dialogue: ${sentences[0]}\n" +
                "Dialogue: ${sentences[1]}\n"

template.format(sentences)

print(template)
```

Above code works well. So how about `Java` ?

## EDIT

I am sorry I have not described my question clearly. And when I run into my real case I found my code cannot work for me now.

In fact, `template` is read from a file.

```
var sentences = arrayOf("hello", "world")
var template = File("template.txt").readText()

template.format(sentences)
print(template)
```

And template.txt file contains:

```
Dialogue: ${sentences[0]}
Dialogue: ${sentences[1]}
```

**As you see, I want to read file then format the result.**

In addition, I am so sorry about this question. **Because it seems to be changed to how to format string which is read from file.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36498517/283366

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String variable interpolation Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389827/string-variable-interpolation-java)

Comment: Why close my question? Have you read my question?

Comment: @Phil Can please you read my question again?

Comment: According to your edit, it becomes an extremely complicated question..

Comment: Yes，but I cannot delete my question and create new one. So I am so sorry.

Answer (score 4):

The code above is **completely wrong use of `String.format`**. Let me explain why.

In the first two line:

```
var sentences = arrayOf("hello", "world")
var template = "Dialogue: ${sentences[0]}\n" +
              "Dialogue: ${sentences[1]}\n"
```

Here, `template` is already there, it's a `String`, its value is `"Dialogue: hello\nDialogue: world"`, which is the result you see.

If you don't trust me, try replace `sentences` with a non-exist variable name. You'll get a compile error, because the string is connected exactly when you create it. "String template" is just a syntax sugar of `+`.

Then, you've invoked `template.format`, which is actually `String.format`, the returned string is not used.

Since this is already wrong in Kotlin, you can do the same thing in Java easily:

```
String[] sentences = new String { "hello", "world" };
String template = "Dialogue: " + sentences[0] + "\n" +
                  "Dialogue: " + sentences[1] + "\n";

template.format(sentences);

System.out.print(template);
```

This code equals to the Kotlin code you've given.

I guess you want this:

```
String template = String.format("Dialogue: %s%nDialogue: %s%n", sentences);
System.out.print(template);
```

Comment: Is this an answer? (it's also a bit rude)

Comment: I've posted the answer. @JonathanLam

Comment: I don't see how this is any different from my answer.

Comment: I've given an ideal approach (same as you) and the approach same to his example (you don't have)

Comment: You are right. But I will tell you why I should do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)):

```
String[] sentences = { "hello", "world" };
String template = "Dialogue: %s%nDialogue: %s%n";
String result = String.format(template, arr[0], arr[1]);
```

Comment: OPs example with the array is more akin to `MessageFormat`

Comment: @Phil I was not aware of that class. I'll leave this answer up if it helps anyone though.

Comment: In my opinion this would be easier to read with straight string concatenation rather than relying on format strings. The compiler will optimize it automatically with a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @BrianGordon That's also very interesting. I'm not too familiar with Java and I guess I need to learn about these utility classes (i.e., `MessageFormat` and `StringBuilder`

Comment: The asker is not using `String.format`. He's just using string concatation, and did a call on `String.format` and drops the return value, then prints the concatation result.

Comment: @ice1000 OP simply asks for "any convent way to format string using array in Java." He does not mention that he did not want to use `String.format`. (He does not even use `String.format()` because his example is in Kotlin, presumably). He is simply asking how to do it in Java.

Comment: He did use it, `template.format` is the same as `String.format`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `%s` for substitutions in the template file.
Kotlin (Java) will then call the `toString` method for each argument and replace them with respect to the order of the arguments.

```
//template.txt
%s magnificent %s!

//Main.kt
val sentences = arrayOf("hello", "world")
val template = File("template.txt").readText()

template.format(sentences) // hello magnificent world!
```