# Inserting variables into strings

Tags: java

Im trying to insert the total_cost variable into the string in the last few lines without doing the ("its" + total_cost) method. Im trying to replicate the python {total_variable} method in java basically

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Decision2 {
        public static void main(String[] arrgs) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int ticket = 0;
            double total_cost = 0;
            System.out.println("How many tickets do you want to buy?");
            ticket = input.nextInt();
            if (ticket >= 5) {
                total_cost = total_cost + (10.95 * ticket);

            } else {
                total_cost = total_cost + (8.95 * ticket);


            }
            System.out.printf("The total cost is {total_cost}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-printstream-printf

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389827/string-variable-interpolation-java

Comment: [JEP430](https://openjdk.org/jeps/430) on the way!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String variable interpolation Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389827/string-variable-interpolation-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can use java String [Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)
such as

```
String foo = String.format("The total cost is %.2f",total_cost);
```

or if printing use such as

```
System.out.printf("The total cost is %.2f\n",total_cost);
```

Comment: You should never do that. In this case, `System.out.printf(format, params)` is the same as `System.out.println(String.format(format, params))` (add a \n for the newline), except shorter, and idiomatic.

Comment: Oh thank you for letting me know, I think this is a good option tho if you want to store in a String, I'll fix my answer

Comment: Java code should use `%n` rather than `\n` for the line separator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java's String Templates feature.
It is described in [JEP 430](https://openjdk.org/jeps/430), and it appears in JDK 21 as a preview feature.  Here is an example use:

```java
System.out.println(STR."The total cost is \{total_cost}.");
```

Java's string templates are more versatile, and much safer, than features in other languagues such as C#'s string interpolation and Python's f-strings.
For example, string concatenation or interpolation makes SQL injection attacks possible:

```java
String query = "SELECT * FROM Person p WHERE p.last_name = '" + name + "'";
ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
```

but this variant (from JEP 430) prevents SQL injection:

```java
PreparedStatement ps = DB."SELECT * FROM Person p WHERE p.last_name = \{name}";
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```