# Mirror back http query params in the PACT response json body

Tags: java, rest, unit-testing, pact

Using PACT how can I mirror back my http query parameters in my http response body? In other words, consider the following http query : `/rest/contract?hash=C3459H6S`
In my PACT response JSON body I want to have `{hash : 'C3459H6S' ...omitted code}`. The purpose of this is to make PACT responses dynamic rather than static so I won't be delivering the same JSON response for all queries of type `/rest/contract?hash=WHATEVERHASHTHATIS`

Edit: based on @Matthew Fellows's response and after some research I finished with this code right here :

```
@Pact(provider = "myProvider", consumer = "myConsumer")
public RequestResponsePact getContractByHash(PactDslWithProvider builder) {
    return builder
        .uponReceiving("a request for a contract by hash")
        .path("/rest/contract")
        .query("hash=${hashPlaceholder}")
        .method("GET")
        .willRespondWith()
        .status(200)
        .headers(Map.of("Content-Type", "application/json"))
        .body("{\"hash\": \"${hashPlaceholder}\"}")
        .toPact();
}
```

I am getting however this error right here when running my `@Test` :
Pact Test function failed with an exception, possibly due to

```
Mismatches(mismatches=[PartialMismatch(mismatches=[QueryMismatch(queryParameter=hash, expected=${hashPlaceholder}, actual=C3459H6S, mismatch=Expected '${ hashPlaceholder }' but received C3459H6S for query parameter hash, path= hash)])])
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not do something like this?

```
      const dynamicBit = '12345678';
      const interaction = {
        uponReceiving: 'a request for a thing',
        withRequest: {
          method: 'GET',
          path: '/rest/contract',
          query: `hash=${dynamicBit}`,
        },
        willRespondWith: {
          status: 200,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: {
            hash: dynamicBit 
            /*, ...omitted code*/
          },
        },
      };
      return provider.addInteraction(interaction);
```

What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I have updated my question, please have a second look. Thank you!

Comment: OK, I think the question is really about string interpolation in Java? Perhaps see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389827/string-variable-interpolation-java. I'll show you a way to do it with the Pact DSL more idiomatically though.