# Python string 'Template' equivalent in java

Tags: java, python, string, equivalent

Python supports the following operation:

```
>>> s = Template('$who likes $what')
>>> s.substitute(who='tim', what='kung pao')
'tim likes kung pao'
```

(Example taken from Python's official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html))

Is there an equivalent way in Java for performing the exact task?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String s = String.format("%s likes %s", "tim", "kung pao");`

or

`System.out.printf("%s likes %s", "tim", "kung pao");`

you can easily do the templating with this too.

```
String s = "%s likes %s";
String.format(s, "tim", "kung pao");
```

Comment: This is not helpful for me since I want to initiate the template in one part of the code and make the substitution somewhere else.

Comment: `String.format` is more an equivalent of Python's own string formatting (with `%` or similar `"string".format()`). The fundamental of `Template` is being able to replace custom named regions.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at http://www.stringtemplate.org/. Here is an example:

```
ST hello = new ST("Hello, <name>");
hello.add("name", "World");
System.out.println(hello.render());
```

prints out:

```
"Hello World"
```

Comment: does it allow condition based templating?

Comment: @gaurav Do you mean like this: https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ST/pages/1409039/Conditionally+included+subtemplates

Comment: Can't access that link but got it working using the official documentation at https://github.com/antlr/stringtemplate4/blob/master/doc/templates.md#conditionals

Answer (score 2):

Chunk templates (http://www.x5dev.com/chunk) make this kind of thing pretty easy:

```
Chunk c = new Chunk();
c.append("{$who} likes {$what}");
c.set("who", "tim");
c.set("what", "kung pao");
String output = c.toString();
```

Or if you have a `Map<String,String>` already:

```
Chunk c = new Chunk();
c.append("{$who} likes {$what}");
Map<String,String> tagValues = getTagValues();
c.setMultiple(tagValues);
c.render(System.out);
```

Chunk also makes it easy to load templates from a file or a group of files, and supports looping, branching, and presentation filters.

Comment: does it allow condition based substitution?

Comment: yes, full if-elseif-else blocks are supported: http://www.x5software.com/chunk/examples/ChunkExample?example=ifelse&loc=en_US

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is anything equal, but you can do:

```
String s = "$who likes $what";
s.replace("$who", "tim").replace("$what", "kung pao");
```

And you will get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

There's another option answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3655963/10815638). Will repeat it for convenience.

There's a library [org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.9](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/userguide.html) with class [StringSubstitutor](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html). That's how it works:

```
 // Build map
 Map<String, String> valuesMap = new HashMap<>();
 valuesMap.put("animal", "quick brown fox");
 valuesMap.put("target", "lazy dog");
 String templateString = "The ${animal} jumped over the ${target}.";

 // Build StringSubstitutor
 StringSubstitutor sub = new StringSubstitutor(valuesMap);

 // Replace
 String resolvedString = sub.replace(templateString);
```

Still there's a remark. `StringSubstitutor` instance is created with a substitution map and then parses template strings with its `replace` method. That means it cannot pre-parse the template string, so processing the same template with different substitution maps may be less efficient.

The Python's [`string.Template`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/string.html#template-strings) works the opposite way. It's created with the template string and then processes substitution maps with its `substitute` or `safe_substitute` methods. So theoretically it can pre-parse the template string that may give some performance gain.

Also the Python's [`string.Template`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/string.html#template-strings) will process ether `$variable` or `${variable}` by default. Couldn't find so far how to adjust the `StringSubstitutor` to do this way.

By default `StringSubstitutor` parses placeholders in the values that may cause infinite loops. `stringSubstitutor.setDisableSubstitutionInValues(true)` will disable this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `String.format` to achieve this.

http://javarevisited.blogspot.sk/2012/08/how-to-format-string-in-java-printf.html