# Finding special strings within special strings in strings with Regex

Tags: java, regex

There is a HashMap I have which has keys and values inside. I want to replace keys with the values from the map in a string.

In the string, keys are written as this ***@keyName*** or ***@"keyName"*** these should be replaced with ***map.get("keyName")***

Lets say our map is this

```
"key1" : "2"  
"key2" : "3"  
"key3" : "4"  
"key 4" : "5"
"key-5" : "6"
```

So if we process the string **"hello world, I am @key1 years old."**, it will become **"hello world, I am 2 years old."**

Instead of ***@key1***, we could use ***@"key1"***. If we use it without quotes, a white space (space character) or EOF should follow the key name and the key name shouldn't have white space in it. But if the key name has a white space in it, then it should be in quotes.

And if we process the string **"hello world, I am @"key@"key1"" years old."**, at first step it should replace the special string inside the special string and become **"hello world, I am @"key2" years old."** and then with the second step it should be **"hello world, I am 3 years old."**

I have already done it for one special string, it doesn't recognize the special string within the special string. Here is the code:

```
private static Pattern specialStringPattern = Pattern.compile("@\"([^\"]*?)\"|@\\S+");

/** this replaces the keys inside a string with their values.
 * for example @keyName or @"keyName" is replaced with the value of the keyName. */
public static String specialStrings(String s) {
    Matcher matcher = specialStringPattern.matcher(s);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String text = matcher.group();
        text = text.replace("@","").replaceAll("\"","");
        s = s.replace(matcher.group(),map.get(text));
    }
    return s;
}
```

Sorry for my English, and my lack of Regex knowledge. I think it should be easy to get the answer by modifying the code a little bit.

Here is some examples of what I need:

```
There is @key1 apples on the table.  
There is 2 apples on the table.

There is @"key1" apples on the table.  
There is 2 apples on the table.

There is @key 4 apples on the table.
There is null 4 apples on the table.

There is @"key 4" apples on the table.
There is 5 apples on the table.

There is @key@key2 apples on the table.
There is @key3 apples on the table. (second step)
There is 4 apples on the table. (final output)

There is @"key @"key3"" apples on the table.
There is @"key 4" apples on the table. (second step)
There is 5 apples on the table. (final output)

There is @"key @key3" apples on the table.
There is @"key 4" apples on the table. (second step)
There is 5 apples on the table. (final output)

There is @"key @key3 " apples on the table.
There is @"key 4 " apples on the table. (second step)
There is null apples on the table. (final output)

There is @key-5 apples on the table.
There is 6 apples on the table.
```

Comment: Is the solution acceptable for you? 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3655963/2027465

Comment: @VitaliyPro I don't think it is applicable. I thought I explained the rules clearly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made regex that matching your example here:
https://regex101.com/r/nudYEl/2

`@(\"[\w\s]+\")|(?!@(\w+)@(\w+))@(\w+)`

and you just need to modify your function to recursive:

```
public static String specialStrings(String s) {
    Matcher matcher = specialStringPattern.matcher(s);
    boolean findAgain = false;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String text = matcher.group();
        text = text.replace("@","").replaceAll("\"","");
        s = s.replace(matcher.group(),map.get(text));
        findAgain = true;
    }
    if (findAgain) return specialStrings(s);
    return s;
}
```

[Update]
regex: https://regex101.com/r/nudYEl/4

`@(\"[\w\s-]+\")|(?!@([\w-]+)@([\w-]+))@([\w-]+)`

Comment: There is a problem with the characters like '-'. The keys often use a dash between words. Like "key-1". Sorry I missed that.

Comment: Update to this: @(\"[^\"^@]+\")|(?!@[^\"^@^\s]+@)(@[^\"^@^\s]+) This way only @ and " couldn't be used in the key name.

Comment: cool! that worked too, I think you don't need to use `^` for every character inside `[...]` I try this work too `@(\"[^\"@]+\")|(?!@[^\"@\s]+@)(@[^\"@\s]+)`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex:

```
for (boolean hit = true; hit;) {
    hit = false;
    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        if (str.contains("@\"" + key + "\"")) {
            str = str.replace("@\"" + key + "\"", map.get(key));
            hit = true;
        } else if (str.contains("@" + key  )) {
            str = str.replace("@" + key + "", map.get(key));
            hit = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't recognize the inner special String. The first quote of the inner special string finishes the special string.

Comment: @ossobuko you're right. I edited my answer to something different that works (tested too!)

Comment: Oh no! You are going through thousands of keys. This is a frequently used method.