# Best way to use replaceAll for each string in List<String>

Tags: performance, java-8

I have a map which contains regexpr as key and replacer as value and I need to perform a replaceAll for each string in a list.

I should like to know if my answer is correct or if there exists a better way to do that, I'm afraid to see the performance drop. Cause I need to perform this operation on a lot of lists which contain lots of strings.

```
Map<String,String> m_replace = null; //Map which contains regexpr,replacer

private static String replace(String s) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : m_replace.entrySet())
        s = s.replaceAll(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    return s;
}

public List<String> parseList(List<String> input) {
    return input.parallelStream()
                .map(p -> p = replace(p))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: I think its a good enough question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Otha should you replace just *once*? I mean once you applied successfully one `replaceAll` (meaning that the pattern was actually found), shouldn't you stop processing all other map entries?

Comment: @Eugene No i may have to apply several pattern on the same line, btw thanks for correct me :)

Comment: @Otha for each element in the `List` you will have to traverse the entire `Map` then...

Comment: @Otha the complexity as far as I can tell is : `O(n)` for the list times `O(n+c)` for the `Map`; where c - is the capacity of the map and n are the number of entries. That would be a total of `O(npow2)`.

Comment: ok thats bad , i'll testing this soon, i will mesure time to know if I can use this

Comment: @Otha maybe duplicated with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371521/replaceall-with-java8-lambda-functions) question that you can see all of the solutions & comments, especially Holger's solution & comments.

Comment: Well i've tried this morning, all works fine and we dont feel any latency.