# Replace shell environment variables in a string with actual values

Tags: java, replace

I am reading a property file in Java.

```
Properties myProp = new Properties();
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(pathOfPropertyFile);
myProp.load(in);
in.close();
```

The values in the property file have references to Linux shell variables.
For example, an entry in the property file might look like:

```
DATA_PATH=/data/${PROJECT}/${YEAR}${MONTH}${DAY}
```

I have to execute a shell script from java and so I have **ProcessBuilder** instance and also the environment variables (`envMap` as given below):

```
List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
command.add(actualCommand);
command.add(param1);
command.add(param2);
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
Map<String, String> envMap = processBuilder.environment();
```

The `envMap` has the environment variables I require  along with over one hundred (> 100) other environment variables which I do not require.

I want to replace the `${USER}`,`${PROJECT}`,etc., from the property-value string `"/home/${USER}/${PROJECT}/data"` with actual values from the shell.

*I would consider iterating the Map as the last option(as the Map has between 100 and 200 elements to iterate) as it is not an efficient approach.*

Please advise some approach that will fetch the environment variable enclosed by braces from the string, so that I can directly use the get() of the Map and replace. Or, any better approaches are most welcome.

Note:  The reference offered ( [Replace String values with value in Hash Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601011/replace-string-values-with-value-in-hash-map)  that made my question to look duplicate) is not the best fit in my case.

Comment: You add the list to itself `command.add(command);`? What have you tried to replace the variable names in `myProp` with the values you got in `envMap`?

Comment: @SubOptimal Thanks for pointing out the typo error, i corrected it. Iterating the Map elements is not a good idea given the number of elements in the Map (between 100 and 200).

Comment: Are you looking for a way to get `"USER"` from `"${USER}"`? I am not sure what exactly is your issue. Why would you need to iterate the map?

Comment: Marvin, You are right. I'm looking for a way to get "USER" from "${USER}" and the same in the case of other environment variables.  The reference shared by @vefthym iterates the Map.

Comment: @Marco99 ok, I am retracting my close vote then

Comment: Why don't you simply pass the variable names enclosed in `${}` and then just let the shell do the expansion?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou The idea is to use the replaced final string in java context itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are open to using an external library, [`StrSubstitutor`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StrSubstitutor.html) from apache-commons will do exactly what you want:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "DATA_PATH=/data/${PROJECT}/${YEAR}${MONTH}${DAY}";
    Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>();
    env.put("PROJECT", "myProject");
    env.put("YEAR", "2017");
    env.put("MONTH", "7");
    env.put("DAY", "5");
    env.put("OTHER_VALUE", "someOtherValue");
    System.out.println(StrSubstitutor.replace(input, env));
}
```

Output:

```
DATA_PATH=/data/myProject/201775
```

It also has a method to [directly replace system properties](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html#replaceSystemProperties-java.lang.Object-) without the need for an explicit map.

(for a non-external-library approach see [vefthym's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44926425/4616087))

Comment: @Marvin This is pretty straight forward and simple to use.  Thanks for the end-to-end solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it works, but I hope someone can edit to make it work, or at least you get the logic and make it work on your own:

```
command = command.replaceAll("\\$\\{(.*?)\\}", envMap.get("$1"));
```

Here, I am assuming that `command` is a String (not a List) and that all environment variables exist in your Map (otherwise you should check for null and handle this case as you wish).

A bit of an explanation:

this regex is looking for the pattern "${something}" and replaces it with `envMap.get("something")`. In this example, we use parentheses to mark "something" as a group, which can then be retracted as "$1" (since we have only one group, i.e., only one set of parentheses). 
The question mark '?' is the non-greedy operator here meaning to stop at the smallest possible regex match (otherwise it would find a singe match for the first "${" until the last "}".

Comment: The call to `envMap.get("$1")` would simply pass "$1" unchanged to the `get` method. You probably need to use a Matcher to get the actual string inside `${...}` and _then_ pass that to `get`.

Comment: @Marco99 it's not a trivial change. The basic idea is to use a `Matcher` object (see [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) ) using the regular expression pattern shown above as the first argument to `replaceAll`. Or look at the source code for `StrSubstitutor` (from Marvin's answer) to see how it's implemented.

Comment: @Marco99 I've just found [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43372206/638028) that shows exactly what I was thinking about.