# replace $name with name column in excel

Tags: java

I have a java code that replaces **name** from **names** column in excel. I want code to be dynamic
like:

Dear $name

Your code is $code,

However I am not supposed to use %s as I am not sure of column sequence. How can I do it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How you do this currently, show your code please

Comment: The template would look like EMAIL_BODY_TEXT="Dear %s,<br><br>"
   + "In Referenece to our conversation on 12-12-1093, I would like to offer you a discount of %s <br>"
   + "Hope u had a pleasant experience <br><br>"
   + "Thanks and Regards, <br>"
   + "******* "                     . To call this , the code would be String message=String.format(EMAIL_BODY_TEXT,"xyz","123"); the value xyz and 123 are read from excel sheet. But I need to add $name which is linked to name column of excel sheet.

Comment: Please update the question with your comment's content.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655424/string-replacement-in-java-similar-to-a-velocity-template

Comment: Thanks Markus, It helped a bit. But real issue is mapping of excel column .For example is there any way that I can link one column of table say emailId to ${emailId} of string subsr.?? Or I have to parse each row and give value at run time??                 
                valuesMap.put("email", emailMetaData.getEmailId());
  valuesMap.put("fname", emailMetaData.getFirstName());
  valuesMap.put("lname", emailMetaData.getLastName());
  valuesMap.put("ccode", emailMetaData.getCouponCode());
  StrSubstitutor sub = new StrSubstitutor(valuesMap);
  String EMAIL_BODY = sub.replace(emailBody);