# Formatting the String, Object C versus Java

Tags: android, iphone, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inserting a Java string in another string without concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772988/inserting-a-java-string-in-another-string-without-concatenation)

In Object C , the string formatting is like this

```
 url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@devices.json?user=%@&pswd=%@",server_name, user,password];
```

What about in Java for Android?
   How does it handle that?

Comment: %s will take care of all placeholder for java?

Comment: Did you actually bother to look at the link/'s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate the strings or use String.format(String format, Object... args)

Concatenate

String url = server_name + "devices.json?user=" + user + "&pswd=" + password

Format

String url = String.format("%sdevices.json?user=%spswd=%s",server_name,user,password);

It is a matter of preference for which one you prefer.

Look up [java.util.Formatter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html) for a table that demonstrates other conversion types.  %s is for string, %d for int ...